# How to globally decrease space between symbols?

Tags: spacing, symbols

In my document, LateX is consistently placing far too much space between symbols, e.g.

[image: bad-spacing]

One way I am improving this spacing manually is using the following

```
Suppose $x\,{=}\,2$
```

which yields something much more reasonable:

[image: good-spacing]

The document renders much better throughout when I use `\,{=}\,` instead of `=` (and other symbols such as `\in`, `>`, etc.).

Is there a way I can by default reduce the spacing around symbols such as `=` and `\in` etc. without having to use the hack shown above in each location? I guess one possibility to define a command `\mysymb` that sets the spacing, although I'm wondering if there is a global setting that I can configure?

Comment: I am also willing to accept that modifying the spacing in this way is a bad idea and that it is best to leave LaTeX to squeeze/stretch the `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` automatically, provided there is a compelling argument.

Comment: using `\,` forces it to use `\thinmuskip` which seems terribly tight spacing and less than the `\medmuskip` used around binary relations such as `+`

Comment: your initial spacing looks much more than the default, but you showed no code that produced that image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default spacing around a `\mathrel` atom such as `=` is `\thickmuskip`  the default setting is

```
\thickmuskip=5mu plus 5mu
```

the first setting looks best to me

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

default
\[3=1+2\]

hmmm
\thickmuskip=3mu plus 2mu
\[3=1+2\]


hmmmmm
\thickmuskip=1mu plus 1mu
\[3=1+2\]


\end{document}
```

Although you could of course also reduce `\medmuskip` to be more consistent.